# In android, which layer of code handles multiple RILs, e.g. 3G vs 4G

Tags: android, 3g, 4g, ril

I'm trying to figure out the preferred way of handling more than one "vendor RIL" on an android device. Suppose I have two distinct radios, one 3G and one 4G, each with its own vendor RIL (assume Gingerbread release). Some questions:

Would this require two separate instances of the RIL daemon (rild.c), and if so what bit of code (above the RIL daemon, I assume) arbitrates the connections?

Does android have built-in support for multiple RILs at all?

I'm digging through the source trying to figure this out, so any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question...There is no built-in support for multiple RILs. You have to roll your own :(